Show hide PayPal SDK based on date
I've seen other posts similar to this. I post this question because my functionality works at least in part!
I can display this code to give you an idea, but the long and the short of it is, the ensuing div tags with a PayPal SDK for a second button do not show. I initially have both main divs for show and hide set to none, and based on date, they'll show or be hidden. Pretty basic.
I have an "early bird" price with one SDK button, and then a second, that after Q1 will expire and hopefully show the second, regular rate with that part of the SDK and hosted button.
To test if the latter was working, I painted text within it. The text does show, meaning the div tag does fire off, it's just the rest of the ensuing, embedded div tags with the SDK do not show. If I take away the other SDK button set it will show, so it can be done, just so far not dynamically.
My main, underlying question here is, do we think this is something the SO community would know or should I be addressing the PayPal community with type of question?
Any and all feedback is welcomed, and if you think it does any help to post the nuts and bolts of the code here I will.
Thanks!
